# How test Play Framework API in postman.?

Tags: json, rest, postman

How to pass json parameter in postman for testing play framework api?

```
<http://localhost:9000/app/run>
parameter={"command":"getNewsCount","params":{"buysTimestamp":1490086579473,"newsTimestamp":1490088789161}}

Headers=Content-Type application/json
```

when I pass json parameter for test api I get null in my api.

Comment: You'll need to add more information here. What is it you are trying to do? Pass a JSON body? Use the body tab instead of the params tab.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in testing any rest API.

According to this issue:

You need to get logs from the play server; then you will be able to read what happens or post them there to show peoples what happens.

If you do not see any errors in the log, then you need to debug the controller action that works wrong.